# Javascript - Adding Full Screen Video to Image Slideshow

Tags: javascript, video, slideshow

I need assistance as to how I would add a short video clip to display along with my image slideshow.  Below is the JavaScript slideshow which works fine with images, I would like to add videos alongside with the images as part of the slideshow. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var img1 = new Image();
            img1.src = "path/image1.jpg";

        var img2 = new Image();
            img2.src = "path/image2.jpg";

        var img3 = new Image();
            img3.src = "path/image3.jpg";

        var img4 = new Image();
            img4.src = "path/video.mp4";

        var galleryarray = [img1, img2, img3, img4];

        var curimg = 1;

        function rotateimages(){
            $( "#slideshow" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
            document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", galleryarray[curimg].src)
            curimg=(curimg<galleryarray.length-1)? curimg+1 : 0
         });
        $( "#slideshow" ).fadeIn( "slow" );
        }
        window.onload=function(){
            setInterval("rotateimages()", 5000)
        }
```

HTML:

```
<img id="slideshow" src="images/image1.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to create a [`video`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) element instead of a `img` one.

```
function img(src) {
    var el = document.createElement('img');
    el.src = src;
    return el;
}

function vid() {
    //Accepts any number of ‘src‘ to a same video ('.mp4', '.ogg' or '.webm')
    var el = document.createElement('video');
    el.onplay = function () {
        clearInterval(sliding);
    };
    el.onended = function () {
        sliding = setInterval(rotateimages, 5000);
        rotateimages();
    };
    var source = document.createElement('source');
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        source.src = arguments[i];
        source.type = "video/" + arguments[i].split('.')[arguments[i].split('.').length - 1];
        el.appendChild(source);
        }
        return el;
    }

var galleryarray = [img('path/image1.jpg'),
                    img('path/image2.jpg'),
                    img('path/image3.jpg'),
                    vid('path/video.mp4', 'path/video.ogg')];

var curimg = 1;

function rotateimages() {
    $("#slideshow").fadeOut("slow");
    setTimeout(function () {
        curimg = (curimg < galleryarray.length - 1) ? curimg + 1 : 0
        document.getElementById('slideshow').innerHTML = '';
        galleryarray[curimg].style.width = "100%";
        galleryarray[curimg].style.height = "100%";
        document.getElementById('slideshow').appendChild(galleryarray[curimg]);
        if (galleryarray[curimg].tagName === "VIDEO") {
            galleryarray[curimg].play();
        }
        $("#slideshow").fadeIn("slow");
    }, 1000);
}

var sliding;
window.onload = function () {
    sliding = setInterval(rotateimages, 5000);
    rotateimages();
    //FullScreen won't work in jsFiddle's iframe
    document.getElementById('slideshow').onclick = function () {
        if (this.requestFullscreen) {
            this.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (this.msRequestFullscreen) {
            this.msRequestFullscreen();
        } else if (this.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            this.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (this.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            this.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        }
    }
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/j0mem6kr/7/)

Comment: Yes. Prior to posting my code did work. It was only the video part that didn't load. Is there way to autoplay the video when it loads?

Comment: Yes, call `.play()` on the video element after loading it.

Comment: Yes, as @SpencerWieczorek just noticed you have to call `play()`, but not at loading, but only when shown by `rotateimages`. see edit

Comment: I also added a fullscreen method (onclick) as requested in title, but it won't work in jsFiddle's iframe

Comment: +1 , Although note that you want to change you fiddle link to: `http://jsfiddle.net/j0mem6kr/` , removing the trailing `/`.

Comment: Oh man! Freaking awesome. I thought it wasn't possible.  Thank you greatly, I learned a great deal on this. Again, many thanks.

Comment: @FrankieBermudez I added a new way that might be helpful if you're dealing with a high number of elements. See the *edit* I keep the original answer though because it was the accepted one but I'm ok to delete it if not needed anymore

Comment: Thanks for the example. Why there is white screen between media change?

Answer (score 0):

[**Fiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/5mka5yfc/2/)

#### Approach

What we will need to do is have two elements to show, using the `<img>` element to show images, then the `<video>` element to show videos. When `rotateimages()` is called we will want to detect if the element is a `video`, switch to the `<video>` element and hide the `<img>` element. Otherwise if it's a `image`, then do vise-versa if we are moving to an `image` hide `<img>` and show `<video>`.

So the HTML will have something like this:

```
<img id="slideshow" src="..." width=300 height=300 alt="Slideshow">

<video width="300" height="300" id="slideshow_vid" hidden>
    <source id="slideshow_src" src="...">
</video>
```

The `video elements` in JavaScript I will simply use an `Object` with a `type` and `src` property like so:

```
var moive1 = {
    src: "...", 
    type: "video"
};
```

#### Implementation

To implement this we will do 3 steps in the `rotateimages()` function.

First `.hide()` the appropriate element based on if we are on a `video` or `image` element. Otherwise both the `<video>` and `<img>` tags would be showing, ruining the effect.

```
$( "#slideshow" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
    nextSlideshowElement()
});
$( "#slideshow_vid" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
    nextSlideshowElement()
});
```

Where `nextSlideshowElement()` is defined as:

```
// Place next element on #slideshow if it's not a video.
function nextSlideshowElement(){
    if(galleryarray[curimg].type != "video") 
        document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", galleryarray[curimg].src)    
}
```

Then we move to the next element in our array, as you have already defined:

```
curimg = (curimg<galleryarray.length-1)? curimg+1 : 0
```

Finally we do the transition effects between moving between a `video` to an `image` or `image` to `video`. Note that I added a delay, giving time so the next element wont appear below, placing the two `<video>` and `<img>` items in the same place. I used `load()` to start the video from the beginning.

```
if(galleryarray[curimg].type == "video") {
    // Show <video> slideshow element
    $( "#slideshow" ).fadeOut( "slow" );
    $( "#slideshow_vid" ).delay( 600 ).fadeIn( "slow" );
    // Set the video src to the array elements src.
    $( "#slideshow_src" ).attr("src", galleryarray[curimg].src);
    $( "#slideshow_vid" ).load();
    $( "#slideshow_vid" ).delay( 600 ).get(0).play();
}
else { 
    // Show <img> slideshow element
    $( "#slideshow_vid" ).fadeOut( "slow" );
    $( "#slideshow" ).delay( 600 ).fadeIn( "slow" ); 
    $( "#slideshow_vid" ).get(0).pause();
}
```

Comment: Spencer. Quick question. Is there a way to store all the media (images and videos in one directory instead of specifying each item individually?  I'm also having an issue in which I can't view videos offline on the slideshow. Thanks.

Comment: @FrankieBermudez Certainly, the online images are just an example. If for example this file was in the same directory as the images you just need to say: `src="imageName.png"`. Or you can have a `img` directory: `src="img/imageName.png"`.

Comment: Thanks. Which line of code would I need to alter to make the slideshow loop?

Comment: var sliding;
            window.onload = function () {
                sliding = setInterval(rotateimages, 20000);
                rotateimages();
            }

Comment: I had the slide running for about an hour and then the screen went blank and that was the end of the show. I was playing it in Chrome. Odd.