# create personalised videos based on user values

Tags: javascript, android, phonegap

I'll do my best to explain my question clearly so apologies if it isn't crystal clear.
What I want to know (if it's possible) is how you would create a generic video, and somehow pass variables into some form of method, that would turn the video into a personalized video for the user based on their details. A good example of this is the Facebook videos that pop up every now and again saying "Hey, you've been friends with this person for x number of years! here's a video!" then the video is maybe 30 seconds of details about the friendship.

I can't imagine Facebook manually create those videos for billions of users, and that is my question, How is this done?

I'm looking at building an android app and potentially IOS as well.

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook knows who your friends are and has access to both timelines and may look for tags or optical recognition to collect together a bunch of photos.

You can then put together process like a slideshow with variable text holders, the kind of thing you can find as an after effects template that will then output a video. There are a number of services who will do this for you too.

https://spark.adobe.com/make/slideshow-maker/
Animoto is another. If you look more in this direction I am sure you will be able to learn more about how it's done or find a third party who will do it for you.

You may find this the answer you are looking for: [Javascript - Adding Full Screen Video to Image Slideshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427594/javascript-adding-full-screen-video-to-image-slideshow)

Comment: Thanks for the response. The link at the end was very useful.